# Why does LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication open in browser when app is not installed in android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tested in both android and IOS devices for this. In IOS devices, LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication works fine. It doesn't open to safari browser when there is no related app installed. But in android, when the app is not installed, it redirected to the default web browser. In summery, externalNonBrowserApplication works the same as externalApplication in android. Is there any way to fix it?

```
await launchUrl(
  Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/poet.circle/"),
  mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
);
```

This is my code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
```

With this line:

```
mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
```

It is working in both Android & iOS.

Comment: What I wanna do is to stop going to browser when the app is not installed in the android. I don't wanna open it in the in-app web browser.

Comment: For that purpose, use this instead: https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps & https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus